Is it possible to achieve setup/teardown with b.RunParallel() as is with b.Run()?
For benchmarks that need setup, I use b.Run() func to achieve setup teardown, as per docs

A benchmark that calls Run at least once will not be measured itself and will be called once with N=1.

So this seems a good way to setup and (defer) teardown.
func BenchmarkGet(b *testing.B) {
    // Setup for test e.g. httptest.NewServer(handler())
    Setup(fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d", b.Name(), b.N)) // fmt.Printf("Setting up for %s\n", testName)
    defer Cleanup(fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d", b.Name(), b.N)) // fmt.Printf("Cleaning up for %s\n", testName)
    b.Run(b.Name(), func(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            //test
        }
    })
}

Setup and Cleanup are called once, thus producing output with -v
BenchmarkGet
Setting up for BenchmarkGet-1
BenchmarkGet/BenchmarkGet
BenchmarkGet/BenchmarkGet-4             206295442            6.118 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
Cleaning up for BenchmarkGet-1
PASS

But for b.RunParallel(). this is not the case.
func BenchmarkParallel(b *testing.B) {
    // Setup for test e.g. httptest.NewServer(handler())
    Setup(fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d", b.Name(), b.N))         
    defer Cleanup(fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d", b.Name(), b.N)) 
    b.RunParallel(func(p *testing.PB) {
        for p.Next() {
        }
    })
}


//Output with -v 
BenchmarkParallel
Setting up for BenchmarkParallel-1
Cleaning up for BenchmarkParallel-1
Setting up for BenchmarkParallel-100
Cleaning up for BenchmarkParallel-100
Setting up for BenchmarkParallel-100867656
Cleaning up for BenchmarkParallel-100867656
BenchmarkParallel-4
100867656           11.88 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op

Is it possible to achieve same with b.RunParallel() as with b.Run()
Tried setup and teardown using

testing.TestMain func.
init func.
b.ResetTimer etc.

While these are popularly suggested and TestMain being the one introduced for this very purpose, still they don't provide what b.Run() provides.

Setup teardown per benchmark. no impact on other benchmarks and tests.
TestMain is global for the package, same setup/teardown applied to ALL tests.
Reset timer saves from excluding the timing, but resources are created and thus less efficient than b.Run()

I may be completely incorrect in using this this way, but my expectation is that this should be possible with b.RunParallel similarly to b.Run().

I don't know but wouldn't it be simpler to just StopTimer and StartTimer?

@Volker  RunParallel advises against using  Start/Stop/ResetTimer
imo simplest way is how Run() func does it,

If a benchmark needs some expensive setup before running, the timer should be reset with b.ResetTimer, see the example.
You can do this also before calling b.RunParallel. For cleanup there is b.Cleanup.
While documented behavior, I would not use the fact that b.Run is only called once. Also, there is no documentation whether the subbenchmark will run during or after the main function, so you could call you cleanup function before the subbenchmark is run.
